# How to search by categories using Drupal trip_search module

Tags: drupal

I am using trip_search module and when searched it displays all the results. I just want search result  only from one table. What can I do for this? And I don't have any idea about function module_invoke used in trip_search module. Hope to get answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the trip_search (SQL search) settings at `index.php?q=admin/settings/trip_search`, like

- Advanced search page selection criteria options: Enable or disable the display of particular form sections on the advanced search page: Content type / Categories / Omitted vocabularies / Users / Omitted users
- Filtering of results: will allow the user to further filter the search result set, by category / content type / user
- Ranking of results

?

for `module_invoke`, check the [Drupal](http://drupal.org/handbooks) [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_invoke) and [Google](http://google.com/search?q=module_invoke). in short, it invokes the specified [*hook*](http://google.com/search?q=Drupal+hooks) (`trip_search`, `search_item`) in all modules and collects the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first question is "Why are you using trip_search?"

It is not commonly used any more so you are unlikely to have much success with it.